# PHP fgets() strict !== operator

Tags: php, file

I saw the code below in the PHP Documentation for [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)():

```
while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $buffer;
    }
```

My question is: why is there a strict `!==` ?

Why can't you just do:

```
 while ( $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096) ) {
            echo $buffer;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string containing just `0` is considered falsy. So if the last line of the file is just `0` (with no newline at the end), that line of the file will not be echoed. The strict comparison ensures that the loop only ends when `fgets()` returns `false` because it reached the end of the file or got an error.

Comment: Thanks. Just saw what you said here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php